# What does invalid operand to binary expression mean?

Tags: c++, fstream, extract, fileparsing

I am new to C++ and want to parse a line from a file. I am using `fstream` and extractors. I keep receiving the following error in xcode:

```
invalid operand to binary expression.
```

I have no idea what this means. I looked long and hard and have not been able to find anything helpful.

```
int x;
int y;
fileIn >> x >> y;
```

The error is on the third line. `fileIn` is an `fstream` object that is *static* and declared and instantiated in another method that is located in the same class. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say "fileIn is an fstream object that is static and declared and instantiated in another method that is located in the same class" I guess it is a pointer, really.

Therefore, the syntax should be:

```
(*fileIn) >> x >> y;
```

Comment: If I had a reputation on this website I'd one up your reply. lol Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the blessing. I would appreciate marking the answer as correct, too.

Comment: It says I have to wait 7 minutes. I definitely will when it lets me.